# Dificuldade em executar o emulador para Android

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, delphi-xe5, emulador

Não estou conseguindo rodar o emulador do ***Android***.

Se tento executar o applicativo recebo uma mensagem da *IDE*:

> The Selected emulator is not running. Do you want to start it?

Claro, não tem emulador rodando e a *IDE* também não consegue iniciar.

Ao abrir o ***Android SDK Manager*** / ***Android Virtual Device Manager***, selecionar o *device* e clicar em *Start* recebo o seguinte:

[image: Tentativa de inicialização da Máquina Virtual]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Temo que isso possa ser tempo perdido. No XE5 a embarcadero recomenda que utilizemos um dispositivo android para debugar nossas aplicações, uma vez que o emulador não funciona a contento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o seguinte.

Copie a pasta `.android` localizada na partição `D:\` para a pasta raiz do seu usuário, por exemplo `C:\Users\Foo\` isso deverá resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

se  houver acento no nome do seu usuário do windows o sdk não consegui reconhecer o caminho, nesse link a baixo tem uma explicação de como resolver esse tipo de problema:

http://celeiroandroid.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/panic-could-not-open-avd-config-file.html